# How to (simply) personalize Alert in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, alert

I have made this `Alert`:

[image: my alert]

whose code is:

```
public static boolean ignoreExcellence() {
    ButtonType yes = new ButtonType("Ignora certificato di eccellenza", ButtonBar.ButtonData.YES);
    ButtonType no = new ButtonType("Cerca strutture senza certificato di eccellenza", ButtonBar.ButtonData.NO);

    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION,
                "Non hai selezionato il Certificato di Eccellenza. Vuoi ignorararlo?", yes, no);
    alert.setTitle("Attenzione");
    alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

    return result.orElse(no) == yes;
}
```

How can I personalize this alert so that `"Message"` is `"Non hai selezionato il Certificato di Eccellenza. Vuoi ignorararlo?"` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `alert.setHeaderText("Non hai selezionato ...");`